# MySQL Where Column = Distinct

Tags: mysql

I have the following columns:

```
ID    DATE                   NAME
1     2012-10-03 12:00:00    John
2     2012-10-03 13:00:00    Adam
3     2012-10-10 10:00:00    Pete
```

And I want to return all columns between certain dates, but only 1 column per month and day. I have tried using a distinct statement, but I can't seem to return all columns and only by month and day (it takes the time into consideration as well).

The results i'd like are:

```
ID    DATE                   NAME
1     2012-10-03 12:00:00    John
3     2012-10-10 10:00:00    Pete
```

Since those two columns do not share the same month and/or day. I know this is a simple statement. Right now i'm using:

```
SELECT id, DISTINCT date, name FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

Comment: what is you basis that you choose `JOHN` instead of `ADAM`?

Comment: It doesn't really matter, the names are just showing they are separate entries. I just need the count of all separate dates on the entire table.

Comment: what do you mean by `count`? you didn't mention that in your question. :D

Comment: I'm using the query to count the records...but I need the actual date returned so i'm not using a count in the actual query. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this query -

```
SELECT ID, DATE, NAME FROM table
GROUP BY DATE(DATE)
```

...add WHERE condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can try grouping them by date

```
SELECT id, date, name 
FROM table 
WHERE date BETWEEN ? AND ?
Group By date_format(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a 
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT DATE(`DATE`) dateOnly, MIN(ID) minID
            FROM tableName
            GROUP BY DATE(`DATE`)
        ) b ON a.ID = b.MinID AND
                DATE(a.`DATE`) = b.dateOnly
WHERE a.`DATE` BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bdbe1/1)